How do I remove non-semantic trash code like <app-menu>e.t.c. in Angular SSR?
In Vue and React, this isn't usually a problem. They don't break SEO with non-existent tags. I'm new to Angular SSR, and when I tried it, I was horrified. It feels like Angular considers leaving trash behind as normal. Maybe I missed a setting, but I haven't found anyone else acknowledging this issue. Even tutorials on YouTube do SSR without addressing this.
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import express from 'express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname, join, resolve } from 'node:path';
import bootstrap from './src/main.server';

/* HACK for remove angular trash code
TODO need to understand how to do it with default functional of */

function modifyHtml(html: string): string {
  html = html.replace(/<app-root([^>]*)>([\s\S]*?)<\/app-root>/g, '<div id="root"$1>$2</div>');
  html = html.replace(/<(\/?app-\w+|router-\w+)[^>]*>/g, '');
  return html;
}
/* The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions. */

export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const serverDistFolder = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
  const browserDistFolder = resolve(serverDistFolder, '../browser');
  const indexHtml = join(serverDistFolder, 'index.server.html');
  const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();
  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', browserDistFolder);
  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('**', async (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, headers, originalUrl, baseUrl } = req;
     try {
      const renderedHtml = await commonEngine.render({
        bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl }],
      });
      // modify before send client
      const modifiedHtml = modifyHtml(renderedHtml);
      res.send(modifiedHtml);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  });
  return server;
}
function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 8082;
  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}
run();

Thank you in advance for your advice. GPT and official documentation haven't helped much either. If I missed something, I apologize.

I don't see how the custom tags are "breaking SEO". We have custom elements (web components) as a web standard. Custom elements and Angular components look the same for web crawlers. In both cases, it should not have any negative impact on SEO, assuming the crawler is implemented correctly. https://dev.to/stuffbreaker/seo-and-web-components-2023-edition-3l6i

If you want to solve this, try changing the selector which is used for components, the default is the component selector, instead go for attribute selector
BEFORE:
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    ...
})
...

AFTER:
@Component({
    selector: '[appRoot]',
    ...
})
...

The new HTML will be.
index.html
...
<div appRoot></div>
...


Cool! Thank you!
Do you know how to remove  from build too?

@SimonLazarev That is a tough one, since its a fundamental element of routing, would recommend not removing it, for components this selector is the way to go! sorry I don't know how to fix this one! :(

When document is build the tag  is not need anymore and it's not a fundamental anymore.
function modifyHtml(html: string): string {  // HACK for remove angular trash code  // TODO need to understand how to do it with default functional   return html.replace(/<router-outlet[^>]*><\/router-outlet>/g, '<div></div>'); }
This code can remove router-outlet and not broke DOM model, but it's still hack :(

@SimonLazarev If you want the routing to work after the page is rendered, you will face issues, so I am recommending against it! The router-outlet is used by angular routing to navigate to the differnet routes without page refresh
